# The method attach(Fragment) is undefined for the type FragmentTransaction - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

For some reason the system does not find the attach and detach methods for Fragments like in here...

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
        // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
        ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }
```

I get the above error in the compiler.
The project is based on Android 3.1 level 12. And I already resinstalled the complete Android 3.1 SDK.

I though all that would be part of Android 12?

All the other Fragment methods and references work fine.

Many thanks!

Comment: Make sure that `mFragment` is an `android.app.Fragment`, not an `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` from the Android Support package.

Comment: I do not have any reference to the support package - also not in the build-path. Could it still be a support Fragment? What should I do?

Comment: "Could it still be a support Fragment?" -- no, then that's not the problem. It is easy to get the two Fragment implementations mixed up in the imports, which is why I asked. Make absolutely certain that your Android project has API Level 13 as its build target (Android section in project properties).

Comment: I tried all the levels now and only starting with Android 3.2 level 13 the error goes away. The higher the Android level is one uses for the app the lower the probability that many users will actually have this one installed. No idea why attach is only available starting with 13????

Comment: ps is attach not included in the v4 support library? Also, I always get errors when writing import android.support.v4.app.Fragment in a level 11 project. It does not even find the imported package even though it's in the lib folder of the project and in the build path.. (I thought that Fragments are available with 11 - as it states in the docs!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Level 12 doesn't have `FragmentTransaction.detach(Fragment)` API.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html (filter by API level 12 on top right corner)

Comment: very good to know the filter function! But now there is a new problem combining the action bar and the support v4 Fragment class. (for those who also tried this, see my follow up question)